# Difference between static files and media files: How to show some upload image in template

Tags: django, image, templates, static

I am new to Django and still struggling to grasp static files and media files.

IF i want have images that are stored in models with  `mode.FilePathField` on my website that are static then how should i call them properly in my templates:
using static tag Like that:`{% static project.image.path %}`
or that just by calling it: `{{ project.image.path }}`

When reading tutorial i got answers that the first one but then it doesn't work. It gives me wrong paths
i will get `'static/MyApp/static/Myapp/img.jpg'` instead of `MyApp/static/Myapp/img.jpg`

I would be really glad for an example of static files called dinamacally.

Comment: Please past your models.

Comment: Where's your models code ?

Answer (score 0):

According with django doc [here](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/static-files/index.html#:%7E:text=Websites%20generally%20need%20to%20serve,contrib.&text=This%20page%20describes%20how%20you%20can%20serve%20these%20static%20files.)

Web App generally need to serve additional files such as images, JavaScript, or CSS. In Django, he refer to these files as **static files**. Django provides `django.contrib.staticfiles` to help you manage them.

On the other hand files which are uploaded by the user are called **Media or Media Files**.

**a - When you want to serve static files that's what you have to do first:**

1- Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your **INSTALLED_APPS**

2- In your `settings.py` file of your project, define `STATIC_URL` const like this: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

3- In your **templates**, use the static template tag to build the URL for the given relative path using the configured `STATICFILES_STORAGE` as follow:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
```

4- Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example `my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg.`

5- In developpement you must add following snippet:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**B - Now When you want to serve media files you have to do this:**

1- Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

2- In your `settings.py` file of your project, define `MEDIA_URL` const and `MEDIA_ROOT` const like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

3- In developpement server you must add following snippet:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

4- inside your template i you have to get your media files (Example show your image) you must use url attribut of your model filefield:

```
<img src="{{app_model.model_file_field.url}}" other attribute >
```

Comment: Now you just copied Django Docs... That doesn't help me.

Comment: What's do you want ? Really ?